# Pause button code

Tags: javascript

I keep getting this error "pause_button.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null(anonymous function) @ pause_button.js:6". Not sure what is wrong but here is the code if someone can help me figure this out that would be awesome.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid"),
pauseButton = document.getElementById("vidpause");
function vidFade() {
vid.classList.add("stopfade");
}
vid.addEventListener('ended', function() {
// only functional if "loop" is removed 
 vid.pause();
// to capture IE10
vidFade();
});
pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
vid.classList.toggle("stopfade");
if (vid.paused) {
vid.play();
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
} else {
    vid.pause();
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Paused";
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

is happening here:

```
vid.addEventListener('ended', function() { /.../ });
```

Which means that `vid` is `null`.  Thus, this line didn't find a matching element:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid")
```

The fix, then, would be to have an element which matches that.  (Should I assume it's intended to be a `<video>` element?)  Specifically, that element needs to exist *when the code executes*.  So you might have no element, or you *might* have an element but it's *after* the code.

Contrast this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // this *won't* find the element
    var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
</script>
<video id="bgvid" />
```

with this:

```
<video id="bgvid" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    // this *will* find the element
    var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
</script>
```

Just make sure the element exists when the code runs and that should correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

vid is null on line 6. It means that the code:

```
document.getElementById("bgvid")
```

don´t found any element.

Make sure that element with id 'bgvid' exists on your html or that it is the corret id for element.